# DB2 Federation error in creating Nicknames

Tags: db2, db2-luw, federation, adabas

We are setting up the federation in order to browse data from ADABAS using DB2 federation. We have a Classic Data Architect connection set up and a remote server in DB2 federation configured usign JDBC.
The problem is that when we try to create a nickname using this command:

```
CREATE NICKNAME "JADABAS"."[TABLENAME]" FOR "CACDSJ"."ANAG"."[TABLENAME]";
```

we are getting this error:

> The current transaction was rolled back because of error "-430".. SQLCODE=-1476, SQLSTATE=40506, DRIVER=3.68.61

The DB2-server is a windows.

any ideas?

here the logs:
[Google drive log link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j-c81UVMjUNOjV_FY2ZjL8tXqwxFEmMs)

DB2LEVEL output:

> DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
>   "DB2") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10059" with level
>   identifier "060A010E". Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.900.618",
>   "s170908", "IP24033", and Fix Pack "9". Product is installed at
>   "C:\IBM\WSII\V10.5" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".

Comment: Also edit your question to show the entries that appear in the db2 diagnostics file when the create nickname fails, there should be more details there.

Comment: Edit your question to add the output of the command `db2level` .

Comment: added the output

Comment: Suggest you open a service-request (PMR) with IBM support. Your db2diag shows a severe " Java Virtual Machine aborted!" and a preceding dump. IBM will most likely need that information as part of the db2support tool output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where privileges problems, correcting them now it is working fine.